# Adding an edge/node with a color attribute

Tags: python, networkx

I a using the `networkx` package of Python. The documentation says we can do `H.add_edge(1,2,color='blue')` but the output shows an edge with the default (black) color. When I do `H.add_node(12,color='green')` I get a new node with same default red color.

Comment: Nobody answers the question if I put the networkx tag

Comment: you can have as many tags as you want :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Peter, according to the documentation, to change the color with which nodes/edges are **drawn**, you have to provide the `node_color` argument to the *drawing function*. I.e. from [this example](http://networkx.lanl.gov/examples/drawing/house_with_colors.html), to draw a graph like this (note different colors of nodes):

[image]

The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Draw a graph with matplotlib.
You must have matplotlib for this to work.
"""
__author__ = """Aric Hagberg (hagberg@lanl.gov)"""
try:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
except:
    raise

import networkx as nx

G=nx.house_graph()
# explicitly set positions
pos={0:(0,0),
     1:(1,0),
     2:(0,1),
     3:(1,1),
     4:(0.5,2.0)}

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_size=2000,nodelist=[4])
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_size=3000,nodelist=[0,1,2,3],node_color='b')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,alpha=0.5,width=6)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("house_with_colors.png") # save as png
plt.show() # display
```

Note the `node_color` argument to the second call to `draw_networkx_nodes`. Does this help?

Comment: I am building a graph of 100 nodes. Do I need to set the pos of every node? Can I set it at random? How do I do that

Comment: @Peter: do the colors work and this is a different question? Anyhow, I'm not an expert on the drawing stuff in networkx. It does has a layout engine you can use to automatically draw large graps, read the documentation and see the examples - I'm sure you'll figure it out

Comment: Yes the colors work. I found the layout from the documentation. Thanks Eli